# Strange offset when exporting animation to dae

Tags: animation, export, dae

I'm exporting my skeletal animation to a dae file. The animation looks ok before exporting.

[image]

but once exported, if I import the dae file into a blank blender scene, the animation will be stretched. it seems that there is an offset between the bones and the mesh that causes this. but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

the same dae file looks even worse inside MacOS's finder:

[image]

What's wrong? How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Could it be un-applied transformations that get lost at export ?

Comment: it seems to be a bug, I filed a bug here https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/115969#issuecomment-1082268